# Silverlight, custom object for shapes

Tags: silverlight, shapes, custom-properties

I am studding Silverlight. I have an application where I create Polygons in `UserControl_Loaded` method. During creation stage I add MouseLeftButtonUp event handler like this:

```
polygon.MouseLeftButtonUp += MouseButtonEventHandler_MouseLeftButtonUp;
```

All polygons have the same handler.

My goal is to use a custom object when I click on a polygon.

For instance, I have two polygons; both of them have `int MyCustomInt32` property. The property is set during creation stage. For the first polygon it is set to 10, for the second one to 20. When the event fires I would like to retrieve and set MyCustomInt32 value. Of course, the value should be different, it depends on which polygon I click.

Is it possible to do in Silverlight?

Thank you.

Comment: You might want to take a few minutes to review your previous questions, are there any where you can accept an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the sender parameter to your custom class type:-

```
private void MouseButtonEventHandler_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender,  MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var polygon = (MyCustomPolygon)sender;
    int x = polygon.MyCustomInt32;
}
```

**Edit**:

In reponse to your comment, the subject of actually creating an implementation of a custom control is too wide.  There are however plenty of articles out in web land to review.  A couple of examples are:-

- [Creating a Silverlight Custom Control The Basics](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Creating-a-Silverlight-Custom-Control-The-Basics.aspx)
- [Craft Custom Controls for Silverlight 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc721611.aspx)

There are plenty more found with the simple web search "Custom Control Silverlight".

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please provide an code snippet how to implement MyCustomPolygon in you answer? Is it possible to make a new class and inherit it from Polygon class?

Comment: You can't inherit from Polygon, its sealed.  You can create a custom control which contains a Polygon.